# java : How do you create a function that increments a variable that isn't accessible from outside the function?

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

How do you create a function that increments a variable   that isn't accessible from outside the function in java?

I understand this is one of the principles in object oriented design. I am a new programmer trying to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void incrementVariable(){
int var=0;
var++; //increment the variable based on your logic
}
```

`var` is not accessible out the method as its scope is just within the method.
Local variables are only visible to the methods in which they are declared; they are not accessible from the rest of the class.

Comment: Think about the variable as holding some state. If you need to maintain the state longer than the life of the call, a local variable wont work.

Comment: local variable stores the temporary state of the method, so as far as the method is loaded in memory the state will persist. If you need to maintain the state longer than the life of the call use an instance variable or a static variable;

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is one of the "pillars" of object oriented design. Your question could be interpreted a couple of ways, underdog's answer being an example of a local variable that goes out of scope when the method exits. If you want to allow users to increment a class variable that is private to the class, you provide a public method as follows:

```
public class Test
{
    private int counter;

     .
     .
     .
    public void incrementCounterByOne()
    {
         counter++;
    }


}
```